# Logstash: How to remove part of field value (remove url query items)

Tags: logstash

Situation:

In my logs I have a field "Url". In some cases there are one or more query items in the url.

Desired situation:
I'm looking for a way to get rid of the query items in the url (to get a 'clean' url). This in order to have a better analysis in Kibana (what are the most use pages, without query items in url).

What I have done until now is to add a new field "url_nonquery" with the value of the existing "Url" field. Then I use the `mutate { split =>` filter on this new field to split at the ? character. This will result in an array: index 0 with the 'clean' url and index 1 with the query string. But now I don't seem to find out how to delete the index 1.

Does someone has some ideas to help me further with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is a `grok` filter like this:

```
filter {
  grok { match => [ "url", "%{URIPATH:url_nonquery}" ] }
}
```

This would work even if there isn't a ? in the URL.  The `split` method could be troublesome if you don't have a ? in your url.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I was thinking way to difficult for this one. Just one grok line that helped me out.